# How to select files in a directory according to specific string in filename?

Tags: r

I'm reading some netcdf files from a directory into R. The netcdf files are names according to some specific feature of the data.

Here is an example:

```
aa <- c("dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.1962010100_1962123121.nc",
        "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.1972010100_1972123121.nc",
        "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.1982010100_1982123121.nc",
        "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.1992010100_1992123121.nc",
        "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2002010100_2002123121.nc",
        "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2010010100_2010123121.nc",
        "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2012010100_2012123121.nc",
        "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014020100_2014022821.nc",
        "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014120100_2014123121.nc",
        "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2015020100_2015022821.nc")
```

These were collected using the list.files function.

I would like to select (keep) a subset of these filenames (as strings), specifically the files that refer to the data collected in 2010 and 2014.

The year is indicated in the filenames following the '.tmp' string. For example, the first entry would be the year 1962, and so on.

To achieve this, I have tried the following:

```
iyears <- c(2010,2014)
ll <- list()
for (i in 1:length(iyears)){
  ll[[i]] <- aa[grepl(iyears[i],aa)]
}
ll <- c(ll[[1]],ll[[2]])
```

which returns:

```
> ll
 [1] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.1962010100_1962123121.nc" "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.1972010100_1972123121.nc"
 [3] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.1982010100_1982123121.nc" "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.1992010100_1992123121.nc"
 [5] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2002010100_2002123121.nc" "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2010010100_2010123121.nc"
 [7] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2012010100_2012123121.nc" "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014020100_2014022821.nc"
 [9] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014120100_2014123121.nc" "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2015020100_2015022821.nc"
[11] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014020100_2014022821.nc" "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014120100_2014123121.nc"
```

whereas the answer should be:

```
> ll
[1] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2010010100_2010123121.nc" "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014020100_2014022821.nc"
[3] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014120100_2014123121.nc"
```

The problem is that the date string in the file name is as follows:

yyyymmddhh

so, 2010 also appears in

"dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.1982010100_1982123121.nc",

due to 198[2 01 0]1.

Can anyone suggest a method of obtaining the desired result?

Comment: Why don't you just make use of the "tmp" in there too? Like: `grep("tmp.2010|tmp.2014", aa, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `tmp.` portion seems to be a regular feature in the file names, a very direct way to resolve this would be to use that as part of your search string:

```
> grep("tmp.2010|tmp.2014", aa, value = TRUE)
[1] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2010010100_2010123121.nc"
[2] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014020100_2014022821.nc"
[3] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014120100_2014123121.nc"
```

Comment: So, to use the loop I can use grep(paste("tmp",".",iyears[i], sep = ''), aa, value = TRUE). Note that this is only a small example of my code, I actually want to do this for the years 1900 to 2014.

Comment: @EmmaTebbs, you can also probably do more interesting regexes.... And the loop should not be necessary. You can use `paste` to get the `|` separated values you want to look up.

Answer (score 2):

The main trick is to specify where the actual year is in your strings. The following should work:

```
iyears <- c(2010,2014)
ll <- list()

for (i in 1:length(iyears)){
  ll[[i]] <- aa[grepl(paste0("^dayavg_fcst_surf125\\.011_tmp\\.",iyears[i]),aa)] 
}

ll <- c(ll[[1]],ll[[2]])

# [1] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2010010100_2010123121.nc"
# [2] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014020100_2014022821.nc"
# [3] "dayavg_fcst_surf125.011_tmp.2014120100_2014123121.nc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use the `pattern` argument in the `list.files`:

> list.files(path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,
>              full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
>              ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
>
> pattern:   an optional regular expression. Only file names which match
>   the regular expression will be returned.

Ref: R help